# Representing roads consisting of polylines as polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, polygon-creation, visualisation, road

I am working with some roads in London that I downloaded online. The roads are represented as lines like below:

[image]

How can I transform each road from a line into a polygon in QGIS? So that the roads look more like what we see here below (in orange):

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is this about looks or geometry?

Comment: More so about looks as I will then import this into PowerBI. It doesn't have to be ultra perfect.

Comment: If it's about appearance, not geometry, just change the symbology of the roads. You can set a wider stroke width, or use two strokes, one wider than the other to get the outline effect in your image

Comment: Unfortunately changing the thickness wouldn't work for my case. I plan to import it into Power BI and so it has to be a polygon. I know Vince mentioned the buffer tool. However when I try it I get another problem. I posted a new thread to that in my reply below.

Answer (score 4):

You can make polygons with the buffer tool.

Comment: I've tried this tool just now. I seem to be getting another problem. I posted the new problem here:

https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425998/buffer-zone-of-roads-appearing-as-one-big-circle